# A regular normal subgroup of a finite $2$-transitive group is elementary abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

I have not been able to find a proof of this fact so I am trying to prove it myself. This is what I have so far:

Let $G\leq \hbox{Sym}(\Omega)$ be a finite $2$-transitive group of degree $n$. Let $K\triangleleft G$ be a regular normal subgroup of $G$. Then for $\alpha\in\Omega$ the action of $G_{\alpha}$ on $\Omega$ is equivalent to the action of $G_{\alpha}$ on $K$ by conjugation. By $2$-transitivity we know that $G_{\alpha}$ is transitive on the nonidentity elements of $K$, thus all nonidentity elements of $K$ are conjugate. This implies that all the nontrivial elements of $K$ have the same (finite) order. I am having trouble showing that $K$ is abelian. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The common finite order of nontrivial elements of $K$ must be a prime $p$, so $K$ is a $p$-group, and has nontrivial centre, but all of its nontrivial elements are conjugate, so $Z(K)=K$.